# Excel Search Function - Return value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

ok so here is the structure:

Both sheets in same workbook

Sheet1

**A1** blah  **B1** this is a string with a bunch of words    **C1** Result(bunch)

**A2** blah  **B2** this is another string with different words    **C2** Result(different)

Sheet2

**A1** bunch
**A2** different
**A3** apple

I need a formula which finds out if any of the keywords in Sheet2!A:A are in the string in B1 in Sheet1 and so on copied down.  If a keyword does exist in the string, what keyword from Sheet2 is it and put it in column C of Sheet1.

I can get it to say match or no match with the below formula but I need the actual keyword it found. I'm stuck at returning the keyword.

=IF(COUNT(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,B1)),"match","no match")

Comment: "Another Excel doozie" is going to be absolutely meaningless to future readers finding it in a search result. We're not a code writing service where you post your requirements and we churn out code to meet them. Please [edit] your question to make the title more descriptive of the problem you're having and to include at least a minimal effort to write the "formula" you need.

Comment: Thanks for your kind, constructive comments.  I thought nothing of the sort.  But I have reworded as you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken your initial idea and tweaked it a little, you'll want to put the below into your cell C1 on sheet 1.

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,B1)-1)),(FIND(" ",RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,B1)-1)))-1))
```

It essentially trims the string around the word it finds. The SEARCH function finds the first letter, then the FIND function finds the first space after the word. I've not tested what happens if two words from sheet 2 appear in the string, but I would assume it will pick the first word which appears in column A on Sheet 2.